# Flask + Blueprint problem of autosuggest and web form (routing etc)

Tags: javascript, python, forms, flask, routes

I use **Flask + Jinja + Blueprint** to create a very simple webform with autosuggest.

Autosuggest from external API works with Ajax JavaScript, but the selected value is not sent properly when hitting the submit button in the form. I got an internal server error and a wrong key error: I think there is a conflict of requests between autosuggest and form. **The form has two inputs**: one is "predicate" in which autosuggest is used, the other is "place" in which user will type texts without autosuggest. Clues about what needs to be changed would be highly appreciated.

autosuggest.html (simplified)

```
    <script>
        $( function() {    
            $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
                source : function(request, response) {
                    console.log(request.term);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : "http://127.0.0.1:5000/autosuggest",
                        dataType : "json",
                        cache: false,
                        data : {
                            q : request.term
                        },
                        success : function(data) {
                            //alert(data);
                            console.log(data);
                            response(data);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength : 2,
                focus: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.name );
                    return false;
                },
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default form submission
                    $(event.target).val(ui.item.id); // Set the input value to the selected item's name
                    $("#project-id").val(ui.item.id); // Set the hidden input value to the selected item's id
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            return $( "<li>" )
                .append( "<div><b>" + item.id + ":" + item.name + "</b>" + " " + item.description + "</div>" )
                .appendTo( ul );
            };
        } );

    </script>
</head>

    <form method="post" id="search-form">
        <label for="predicate">Please specify a predicate and place</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" 
                name="predicate"
                size="150"
                id="project"
                placeholder="Specify predicate"
></input>
                <input type="hidden" id="project-id" name = "predicate" value="{{ request.form['predicate'] }}">

        <br>
        <label for="place">Please specify a place</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" 
                name="place"
                size="50"
                placeholder="Specify a place">
                </input>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

views.py (simplified)

```
from . import autosuggest
    
@autosuggest.route('/autosuggest/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('autosuggest.html')

@autosuggest.route('/autosuggest/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def autosuggest():
    term = request.form['q']
    print ('term: ', term)
    json_url = f'https://wikidata.reconci.link/en/suggest/property?prefix={term}'
    headers = ''
    r = requests.get(json_url, headers=headers, timeout=3)
    json_data = r.json()
    json_data = json_data['result']
    filtered_dict = [v for v in json_data if term in v['description']]  
    print(filtered_dict)
    resp = jsonify(filtered_dict)
    resp.status_code = 200
    return resp

def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        predicate = request.form.get('predicate')
        place = request.form.get('place')             
        input = [{'predicate': predicate, 'place': place}]
          
        return render_template('autosuggest.html', input=input)
    else:
        render_template('autosuggest.html')
    return render_template('autosuggest.html')
```

__init__.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
autosuggest = Blueprint('autosuggest', __name__)
from . import views
```

Selected value from the autosuggest (ui.item.id) appears in the web form correctly.
Then, type e.g. "Paris" in the second input, and hit the submit button for search:

Error message

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'q'
```

Many thanks!